# Error while calling server side method from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
[WebMethod]
public static string simple()
{
    Home h = new Home();
    h.logout();

    return "dfdsf";
}
public void logout()
{
    Response.Redirect(Config.Value("logout"));
}
```

client side code

```
$('#logout').on('click', function () {
    console.log("dfsnhkjdfsj");
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "Home.aspx/simple"
        }).done(function () {
        console.log("dfsds");
    });

});
```

http://localhost:14605/Home.aspx/simple 404 (Not Found) it is showing that method is not found please help to clear

Answer (score 1):

Try to use without .aspx. `Home` is the name of your Controller and `simple` the name from the methode in your contoller.

```
$('#logout').on('click', function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "Home/simple"
        }).done(function () {
        console.log("Done");
    });

});
```

Comment: Are there the same error when you call http://localhost:14605/Home/simple in your browser ? do you have a firewal who can block?

Comment: bt i am able to call other api's bt this is first time i am working with web method which is not working

Comment: what happen when you call it in browser ? same error (page not found)?

Answer (score 1):

If your server side method is in your code behind, then this should work

JS

```
$('#logout').on('click', function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    PageMethods.simple(yourParameterIfAny, onSucess, onError);
        function onSucess(result) {
            /*OK*/
        }
        function onError(result) { /*Error*/ }
});
```

and your script manager must has its property `EnablePageMethods` to `true`

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
```